# Duplicated magento store from server to localhost -> url rewrite error

Tags: .htaccess, magento, url-rewriting, relative-path, base-url

I duplicated my magento store to my local xampp server. Now none of the images which are referenced with a relative url are displayed (e.g. buttons).

In the phtml files, these images are referenced through

```
<img src=/skin/default/default/images/button.jpg>
```

When I give them an absolute url in form of

```
<img src=http://localhost/magento-test/skin/default/default/images/button.jpg>
```

it works. I tried modifying my local .htaccess with

```
RewriteBase /magento-test/
```

and

```
RewriteBase /
```

and I also changed disabled and endable URL rewrites in the backend. I also have

```
 http://localhost/magento-test/
```

as my base url in the backend.

But the images still don't show up on my local frontend.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid a whole lot of headaches like this, you should reference your images using the `getSkinUrl()` method in your template files.  For example, you'd use:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/button.jpg') ?>" />
```

This builds an absolute reference to your image, using the appropriate URL in your admin area.